# How to clean space after update?

Tags: 8.0, music, nokia-lumia-920, storage, update

I recently updated my Windows Phone 8 firmware but I noticed that it didn't clean the memory.

I have 12 Gb of used space under "others". And I have no idea what's in there.

Plus, I have 9 Gb of music+videos and my music and videos hubs is totally empty!

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately or unfortunately, this is not a problem that has to do specifically with your firmware update.

As mentioned [**here**](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/nokia-microsoft-working-windows-phone-8-storage-bug) is a recognized bug and Microsoft is working with Nokia to address this.

Your firmware update should have enabled the "Storage Check" module- to access this you need to go into Settings and scroll to the bottom of the list.

Detailed instructions are [**here**](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/17034_More_details_on_the_Nokia_spec.php).

Comment: The last firmware update available for my phone and country (France) is the 1249. It does not have "Storage Check"...

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote about it may you can have a look [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16512/11605) That's a know issue until now

[Windows updates failed and using all the space in the phone memory, how to delete?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16512/11605)