# Windows updates failed and using all the space in the phone memory, how to delete?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, storage, crash

I face this issue very often when the update crash in the middle due to connectivity issues and i cannot delete it from the phone or by connecting it through USB.

Even if you try to re-update the new update won't rewrite/delete the existing downloaded files but creates new.

What to do ? 
How to delete the failed download files that's eating up the phone storage ?

This post tries to answer these questions..

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps on your own risk, playing with registry is not good - that's what Microsoft always says

> 1. Download and install **[Interop Tools](https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/interop-tools-appx-windows-10-mobile-t3373675)**

Goto Xda developer forum and download and install a suitable verson of [Interop tools](https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/interop-tools-appx-windows-10-mobile-t3373675).
This app will unlock your phone registry setting and will expose the system folders when connected to USB

> 2. Unlock the file system

Open the application click the hamburger menu --> unlock --> **Interop unlock** 
there will be a button for **Full Filesystem Access** just enable it

> 3. Delete the files in folder

After you connect your phone with USB you will be presented with two root folder Phone  and sd card (*if you have one*). Go to the folder `Phone\Data\ProgramData\SOFTWAREDISTRIBUTION\Download` select all and delete as individual deleting will cause problems

> Small Note:

At times you will not be able to delete files from the Phone directory saying *"Cannot delete xxx: It is being used by another person or program."* to resolve this download and install Unlocker you can find it in [MajorGeeks.com](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker.html) as well in [Github](https://github.com/eladkarako/mods/tree/master/Unlocker) or from [emptyloop.com](http://emptyloop.com/unlocker/)